# DbSet not seeing LINQ definitions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

To clear up the obvious first, I *am*:

- using System.Linq;
- using System.Collections.Generic;
- Have a project reference to System.Core
- My DbSet and DbContext classes are defined properly

The strange thing is, *intellisense* sees it, but I have a compiler warning and it won't compile.

I have tried cleaning the project first, restarting Visual Studio, etc and it still is complaining about:

> Error CS1929  'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

My "receiver" in this case is the compiler statically-determined `var`.

This is a new laptop and a fresh Visual Studio install ... is there something obvious I am missing here?

I wanted these `internal` but tried switching everything `pubilc` just to be sure, but I am getting the same error.

Most people report this when they are missing the using clause for Linq but I have that, and *intellisense sees it* which is where I am getting confused.

Line in question:

```
var excludedUrls = db.ExcludedUrls.ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Is "ExcludedUrls" a string and not an entity? Can you edit your question to include your DbContext setup?

Comment: Note that `var` is not a data type, it is a keyword to infer data type automatically based from value/reference assignment. Check reference for `System.Data.Entity` and `System.Linq`, ensure they're properly registered. Have you tried `db.ExcludedUrls.AsEnumerable().ToList<string>();`?

Comment: I am definetly aware of `var` and I have a project reference to `System.Data.Linq` (there is no `System.Linq`).  Intellisense sees `AsEnumerable` in its generic form only, and wants `ExcludedUrls` for the type.

Comment: Normally when you call `ToLIst` you don't specify the generic type and let C# compiler infer it for you. Any reason of not doing that in your code (apparently `db.ExcludedUrls` cannot be `DbSet<string>`, so simple `ToList()`should work)?

Comment: @IvanStoev That was indeed the case.  Submit that as a response and I will accept.  I was not seeing any overloads in Visual Studio due to the extension methods ... all it was showing me was the generic option.  Removing the generic type and replacing with a straight ToList() resolves this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your code db is a `Dbcontext` with a property `ExcludedUrls` of type `DbSet<TEntity>`

`DbSet<TEntity>` implements `IEnumerable<TEntity>` If you have included `LINQ`, you can use the extension method `Enumerable.ToList<TEntity>()`.

Because of your error I assume that TEntity is not a string. Your code will compile if you leave out the  part:

```
var excludedUrls = db.ExcludedUrls.ToList();
```

However, this might not give a list with the elements you want. Somehow you'll have to convert each excludedUrl in your source sequence to the string representation that you want. If ToString() does not do this, you'll have to create a function yourself:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyTSource> ExcludedUrls {get; set;}
}

void string Transform(MyTSource excludedUrl)
{
    ...
}

List<string> result = dbContext.ExcludedUrls
    .Select(excludedUrl => Transform(excludedUrl)
    .ToList();
```

In words: *from the sequence of excludedUrls, take each element, and transform it to a string using Transform. Convert the resulting sequence of strings to a list, which will be a list of strings*

By the way, did you notice I used `ToList` without mentioning `<string>`? The compiler is able to detect the type of the elements in your input sequence, and can create a List of the same type of elements.

Consider avoiding mentioning the `TSource` when using the Linq functions. This has several advantages:

- less typing
- Easier to change the source sequence, or intermediate linq statements
- Easier to detect the resulting type (and thus easier to detect the error you mentioned)
- It allows the use of anonymous types

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out, is not calling the generic form of `ToList<>` here, but instead calling straight `ToList()`, which returns a generic `List<ExcludedUrl>`.  A thank you to  Ivan Stoev in the comments section for the tip.

I was relying too much on Intellisense hints here and not enough on memory.

As you can see, due to the way extension methods work, it presented me with a `ToList` in its generic form, which is why my code was written the way it was.

[image: ToList generic]